# How to switch IIS Developer Express to "Classic Mode"

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, iis-express

I know how to switch to "Classic Mode" (from "Integrated Mode") in the full IIS via application pool settings. But I can't find how to do it in the current IIS Developer Express beta.

The MS [Developer Express FAQ](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/901/iis-developer-express-faq/) says it can be done, but not how. It's not in the WebMatrix GUI, as far as I can tell. Maybe customization of the Developer Express project file, but I don't see any documentation for that at all.

FYI, there is a Settings area where you can set SSL, CLR version (2.0 in this case), which is where I figure the Pipeline mode (Classic/Integrated) would be, but it's not there.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Using appcmd is not needed, it is best to change this in the project's settings:

1. Click on the web project in the solution explorer
2. Press F4 to get the properties page to show up (not the properties sheet, but the simpler properties window where you set up general things)
3. Look for 'Managed Pipeline Mode', change this to 'Classic'

Comment: In case someone else gets here and doesn't read the whole question (like me :B), this is only available in IIS Express and not with the VS Development Server. Took me a while to pick that up :B

Comment: Thank you! Spent too much time looking for this! In my project the setting was read-only though. I had to go to the project file and change <IISExpressUseClassicPipelineMode /> to <IISExpressUseClassicPipelineMode>true</IISExpressUseClassicPipelineMode>.

Answer (score 4):

I found the following worked with my copy of the IIS Express beta ...

```
appcmd set app /app.name:ExampleApp/ /applicationPool:Clr4ClassicAppPool
```

Note the forward slash at the end of ExampleApp !

Answer (score 1):

What version of VS are you using? The reason I ask is because tooling support for integrated mode is only supported from VS2010 up. See comment here:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/28/introducing-iis-express.aspx

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/114/getting-started-with-appcmdexe

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/870/use-the-command-line-to-run-a-webmatrix-site-or-application/

Comment: I'm just using the WebMatrix GUI--the front-end that launches and configures the service. I'm not using the tooling in Visual Studio. For what it's worth though, VS2010.

Comment: See if you can find a way to set the mode using either the AppCmd.exe or iisexpress command line tools - am adding links above:-)