# Why is IIS Express using <system.web> and not <system.webServer>?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7.5, iis-express, custom-errors

Was using Cassini but switched to IIS Express. My initial thought was that I could remove all `<system.web>` except things like:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="/" />
</authentication>
```

My previous `customErrors` were setup like so:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="/ServerError">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="/NotFound" />
</customErrors>
```

I removed this `customErrors` element when I switched to IISExpress. Now 404's no longer redirect to my nice "NotFound" page.

The AppPool used for my site is `Clr4IntegratedAppPool` which lets me know it's not using Classic.

Why is IISExpress so reliant on `system.web` whereas IIS 7.5 uses `system.webServer`?

Comment: Wich version of Visual Studio are you using? this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748466/how-to-switch-iis-developer-express-to-classic-mode) could help.

Comment: that is interesting as IIS EXpress was based on the IIS7 codebase that uses system.webserver

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well I tried a few different things:

- Changed `existingResponse` to  `PassThrough` as noted [here](http://forums.iis.net/p/1179003/1985595.aspx#1985595)

  `<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">`

Nope!

- Set `TrySkipIisCustomErrors` = `false` as noted in comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619895/how-can-i-properly-handle-404-in-asp-net-mvc/7499406#7499406)

Notta!

I ended up getting it to work by simply changing the `existingResponse` to `Replace`.

- Who knew!

This is how `system.webServer` looks now:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
        <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
        <error statusCode="404" path="/NotFound" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
        <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
        <error statusCode="500" path="/ServerError" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>
```

**Why this solution doesn't make any sense**

> Replace – This value make custom error module to always replace the
> error information with text generated by custom error module. If
> existingResponse is set to “Replace”, errors/exceptions generated by
> Asp.Net/WCF are replaced by IIS7 errors.

http://blogs.iis.net/ksingla/archive/2008/02/18/what-to-expect-from-iis7-custom-error-module.aspx

Comment: Agreed, that makes no sense. +1 for your debugging!