# "This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode."

Tags: asp.net, iis, integrated-pipeline-mode

I have a web application being developed on Windows 8.1, .NET 4.5.1, IIS 8.5 (under Integrated AppPool), Visual Studio 2013 over the default template that includes ASP.NET Identity, Owin, etc. and locally it works fine.

Then I uploaded it to a Windows Server 2008 using IIS 7.5 (Integrated Pipeline) Host and I get:

> ### ***This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode.***
>
> ***Exception Details:***
> System.PlatformNotSupportedException: This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode.
>
> ***Stack Trace:***
>
> ```
> [PlatformNotSupportedException: This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode.]
>   System.Web.HttpResponse.get_Headers() +9687046
>   System.Web.HttpResponseWrapper.get_Headers() +9
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinCallContext.CreateEnvironment() +309
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.GetInitialEnvironment(HttpApplication application) +246
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.PrepareInitialContext(HttpApplication application) +15
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContextStage.BeginEvent(Object sender, EventArgs e, AsyncCallback cb, Object extradata) +265
>   System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +285
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
> ```

I am unable to find anything except for directing the reader to change the pipeline from classic mode to integrated mode, which I already did with no success.

What can I do to fix the problem? Does "Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" not like IIS 7.5 or something?

Comment: Is there anything else in the stack trace?  No frames below HttpApplication.ExecuteStep?

Comment: Nope, only footer that .net framework version number : (Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18067 )

Comment: :( indeed.  Weird question: if you use the Empty Web Application Project template and add a single Default.aspx with the lines <%: System.Web.Hosting.HttpRuntime.UsingIntegratedPipeline %> and <%: System.Web.Hosting.HttpRuntime.IISVersion %>, what does it output on your production server?  Perhaps the runtime is misidentifying the IIS mode in use.

Comment: Returns False, 7.5. But it returns false what ever I set for the pipeline... I set classic it is false, I set integrated it is false too. I forwarded the problem to the host. I am waiting for a response now.

Comment: The problem solved! Thanks. I suppose my host had problems with its system, since even I change the setting into classic or Integrated my app doesnt recognize it. I suppose your code helped me a lot to see it. PS: .Hosting. part is extra it shouldnt be there:    <%: System.Web.HttpRuntime.UsingIntegratedPipeline %>

Comment: connect the application to application pool under integreted mode f.w 4.0

Comment: check the link below, it worked for a lot of people:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/5918197/1912383

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was a strange problem since my hosts IIS shouldn't complain that it requires integrated pipeline mode when it already is in that mode as I stated in my question as:

> I have searched a lot and unable to find anything except for directing the reader to change the pipeline from classic mode to integrated mode that **which I already did with no luck**..

Using [Levi's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/59641/levi) directions, I put <s>`<%: System.Web.Hosting.HttpRuntime.UsingIntegratedPipeline %>`</s> and <s>`<%: System.Web.Hosting.HttpRuntime.IISVersion %>`</s>* on an empty aspx page and told my host what going on and asked them to fix the problem and confirm the problem using the page I uploaded... I checked very often if something has changed at the state of the page and I can see that they struggled 3-4 hours to solve it...

When I asked what they have done to solve the problem, their answer was kind of 'classified', since they said:

> Our team made the required changes on the server

The problem was all with my host.

> * **Update:**  As [Ben](https://stackoverflow.com/users/340045/ben) stated in the comments
>
> 1. `<%: System.Web.Hosting.HttpRuntime.UsingIntegratedPipeline %>` and
> 2. `<%: System.Web.Hosting.HttpRuntime.IISVersion %>`
>
> are no longer valid and they are now:
>
> 1. [`<%: System.Web.HttpRuntime.UsingIntegratedPipeline %>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpruntime.usingintegratedpipeline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and
> 2. [`<%: System.Web.HttpRuntime.IISVersion %>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpruntime.iisversion%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: The [System.Web.Hosting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting(v=vs.110).aspx) namespace doesn't appear to have the [HttpRuntime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpruntime(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

Answer (score 64):

Your Application Pool is in classic mode but your Application need integrated mode to fire.  change it to Integrated Mode:

1. Open IIS Manager
2. Application Pool
3. Select pool that your app are run in it
4. In right panel select Basic Setting
5. Manage Pipeline Mode change to Integrated

Comment: How do I change it if my website is published in a virtual host?

Comment: it's not working for.

Answer (score 59):

Try using `Response.AddHeader` instead of `Response.Headers.Add()`

Comment: This answer works if the exception was caused by adding a header. Tested with MSVS 2010 and Casinni (I think).

Comment: Where would i find  Response.AddHeader

Comment: @drexdrex - Do Have a Response object? What happens if you try Response.AddHeader("X-billpg", "is so very clever."); ?

Comment: I dont now why where to find Response.AddHeader to change it to Response.Headers.Add(), by the way i'm using asp.net mvc5

Comment: I don't understand what code to change, since the stack trace in the question only shows standard MS library code.

Comment: I was dealing with HttpContextWrapper and HttpResponseWrapper and this is the only thing that worked.

Comment: @billpg alternate for `Response.Headers.Remove("`...? I used your solution for `Response.Header.Add`.

Answer (score 32):

I was having the same issue and I solved it doing the following:

1. In Visual Studio, select "Project properties".
2. Select the "Web" Tab.
3. Select "Use Local IIS Web server".
4. Check "Use IIS Express"

Answer (score 9):

This error means the application pool to which your deployed application belongs is not in Integrated mode.

1. Create a new application pool with .NET 4 version selected, and Managed Pipeline mode as **Integrated**.
2. Change your application's app pool to the above created one and try now.

Answer (score 7):

The way to fix this issue is not within IIS.  I was trying to run my application within IIS Express within Visual Studio.  I searched the web and some articles were saying to add an identity tag   to the system.web tag.  This is not the correct way.

The way I was able to solve this issue was to click on the project file and go to properties.
Under managed pipeline, I changed the property value from classic to integrated.

This solved my issue.

Comment: Where exactly did you change the property? Im on VS2013 and in the project properties there is a "Web" tab but there is no "managed pipeline" property.

Comment: Found the answer to my question above here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9023297/837507

Comment: I changed properties setting from "Integrated" to "classic" and back to "Integrated", then saved the changes and things resumed working.

Comment: Press F4 after clicking on Project Link.

Answer (score 4):

I resolved this problem by following steps:

1. Right click on root folder of project.
2. Goto properties
3. Click web in left menu
4. change current port http://localhost:####/
5. click create virtual directory
6. Save the changes (ctrl+s)
7. Run

may be it help you to.

Answer (score 4):

For **Visual Studio 2012** while **debugging** that error accrued

**Website Menu -> Use IIS Express** did it for me

Answer (score 3):

Those who are using VS2012

> Goto project > Properties > Web
>
> Check Use Local IIS Web server
>
> Check Use IIS Express

Project Url http://localhost:PORT/

Answer (score 2):

[GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/issues/162) solution solved the problem for me by adding

- Global.asax.cs: Set AntiForgeryConfig.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader =
  true; in Application_Start:
- Manually add the X-Frame-Options header in Application_BeginRequest

Answer (score 1):

Press F4 in your Project for the property window.
Then change the pipeline mode

[image]

Comment: Super Working Fine. Thanks :)