# "This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode." debugging in VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Visual Studio 2013 created Web App using ASP.NET MVC, Owin, WebAPI.
Everything runs fine in VS 2013. 
However, when I debug in VS 2012 I get the error: "This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode."

I don't know how I can change the IIS settings for the Dev instance.  Other similar solutions do not apply because of this.

["This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313167/this-operation-requires-iis-integrated-pipeline-mode)

Stack Trace:

```
[PlatformNotSupportedException: This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode.]
System.Web.HttpResponse.get_Headers() +9743542
System.Web.HttpResponseWrapper.get_Headers() +9
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.CallHeaders.AspNetResponseHeaders..ctor(HttpResponseBase response) +72
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinCallContext.CreateEnvironment() +434
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.GetInitialEnvironment(HttpApplication application) +303
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.PrepareInitialContext(HttpApplication application) +65
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContextStage.BeginEvent( Object sender, EventArgs e, AsyncCallback cb, Object extradata) +622
System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +285
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an issue when running a 2013 created web app in 2012.  The only way I was able to get it to work was to go back to 2013.

Comment: This resolved the problem. http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/introducing-iis-express

Answer (score 5):

I had the exact same issue. Some of the developers in our team had VS2013 and some VS2012.

To fix this to do the following:

Go into Project properties.
Select Web Tab.
Select "Use Local IIS Web server"
Check "Use IIS Express"

This fixed the issue for us. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

If You are Using Visual Studio 2012.Then Follow the Following Step

1. Go To Solution Explorer
2. Right Click on the Project
3. Click on "Use IIS Express"

Comment: Yep, I think this is what you need to do for asp.net websites. For web applications, use the Project's properties pages.

Answer (score 1):

I try this working :

1- ISS Application Pools PipelineMode change Integrated Mode

2- check Start application pool immediately

3- Authentication in ASP.NET Impersonation Disabled

Thats Enought.

Comment: This worked for us! Should use this option if you already have IIS set up and don't want to launch an express instance.