# Showing Runtime Error in MVC application after deploy

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7.5, windows-hosting

I made a new MVC Project in Visual Studio 2015, then published that package and uploaded into my Windows hosting. After extraction when I browse my URL it shows me this error message. But my application runs on locally just fine.

[image]

Comment: check your supported MVC version on your hosted IIS.

Comment: Have you set `customErrors` to `Off` to see the actual error?

Comment: @ramiramilu now this is showing "System.PlatformNotSupportedException: This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode." this error.

Comment: @KhaledMdTuhidulHossain You need to change App Pool from classic to integrated mode - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313167/this-operation-requires-iis-integrated-pipeline-mode

Comment: @ramiramilu okey , trying and letting you know. And  thanks :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The custom error pages are not enabled for local in your code,
you have to add  `mode="On"`. So `customErrors` looks something like this:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Error" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
  <error redirect="Error/NotFound" statusCode="404" />
</customErrors>
```