# Upload ASP.Net MVC Application using Website Panel gives me error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, websitepanel

Server Error in '/' Application.

This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.PlatformNotSupportedException: This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode.

Source Error:

```
Stack Trace: 

[PlatformNotSupportedException: This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode.]
   System.Web.HttpResponse.get_Headers() +9718022
   System.Web.HttpResponseWrapper.get_Headers() +9
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinCallContext.CreateEnvironment() +309
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.GetInitialEnvironment(HttpApplication application) +244
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.PrepareInitialContext(HttpApplication application) +15
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContextStage.BeginEvent(Object sender, EventArgs e, AsyncCallback cb, Object extradata) +288
   System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +285
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.36365
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313167/this-operation-requires-iis-integrated-pipeline-mode)

Comment: I am uploading site using website panel how to sort out this issue

Comment: I suspect that your website panel will [expose this setting](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22978887/894792) somewhere.  I guess you need to find that setting within your respective control panel.  It will be in relation to the app pool that your website runs under.

Answer (score 0):

Following solution worked for me. You may try it out:

→ If your site is on shared application pool, try dedicated application pool for this site.

→ Keep it on Integrated mode instead of classic

→ Enable 32-bit application support. (If your site is developed in 32 bit machine, you should enable this in your production server as well).

Also, WebsitePanel is no longer maintained. You will not receive any further update/version. It is strongly recommended to replace it. SolidCP is the best alternate option for this.