# This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode. after publish

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I am using anonymous authentication in Managed Pipeline Mode:

[image: image of anonymous authentication=true]

When I’m running this project on VS 2015 its working fine but the problem is when I publish and run its shows me “This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode”.

[image: Image of error message]

Comment: Publish and run from where? Can you please be more specific as what you did and how?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313167/this-operation-requires-iis-integrated-pipeline-mode)

Comment: Check whether the managedpipelinemode of the site in iis is Integrated, ApplicationPools->Managed Pipeline Mode

Comment: as you can see Managed Pipeline Mode is Integrated when I'm running this project on  VS 2015 and its working but when I publish so that publish file shows this error

Comment: What you post is your IIS Express setting in vs. When you publish to IIS manager, you need to reset the setting in IIS Manager